# Facebook CheckIn for version 2.3 using RestFB

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I am working on integrating Facebook Graph API with my J2EE application using RestFB.
I need to programatically checkin a user's place of stay which I get on the basis of location.

But Facebook's graph API version 2.3 has removed the check-in post option.
From what I have read from the docs, this is now possible using the /post/feed url of Graph API.
Using this url, I am able to post message and links, but this does not convey the impression of a user check-in.

Please advise if this is correct or can this be done by some other way.

Comment: When you publish to `/user/feed` there is a place field as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/feed#publish . Set that.

Comment: Thanks for posting this question. I had a similar doubt. Thanks WizKid